# Java Data Structure

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm looking for a data structure that will act like a Queue so that I can hava First In First Out behaviour, but ideally I would also be able to see if an element exists in that Queue in constant time as you can do with a HashMap, rather than the linear time that you get with a LinkedList.

I thought a LinkedHashMap might do the job, but although I could make an iterator and just take and then remove the first element of the iteration to produce a sort of poll() method, I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: A HashMap don't have constant time access, it just looks like this because of the hashing internally. The access time is `O(n)/bucketsize` which might be `1` in most of the cases, but its still `O(n)/bucketsize` (which is linear).

Comment: I describe it as O(log(log(n)) which closely matches what I have observed. c.f. TreeSet is O(log(n)) and a million entries is about 5x slower than 10. HashSet contains() on a million entries is about 1.5x slower than 10 (ignoring caching behaviour) Whether the collection is in cache makes more difference. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often when you want the behaviour of two collections you need to maintain two collections.  A simple approach is to have a Queue and a HashSet, and always perform an add to both and remove from the HashMap when you remove from the Queue.

An alternative is to use a LinkedHashSet. This retains the order elements were added and you can remove the first/oldest element each time.

A third option is to use just a Queue. While you might like O(1) lookup time, you may find it is fast enough to meet your requirements by just searching every element. This might be much faster than you expect. i.e. 1000 elements should be less than 10 micro-seconds.

EDIT: I agree that two collections is best when you don't know the length.

However to show you a brute force search can be fast too. The slowest object to look for is one which is not there. (As it has to compare every element)

```
Queue<Point> points = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Point>(1024);
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
  points.add(new Point(i,i));
Point missing = new Point(-1, -1);
int runs = 100 * 1000;
long start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0;i< runs;i++)
    points.contains(missing);
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Average contains() took %.1f us%n", time/runs/1000.0);
```

Prints

```
Average contains() took 5.1 us
```

You may need to test this for your data type as times of equals() and sizes of queue can vary, but you may be surprise what you can do in 10 micro-seconds and that may be fast enough.

Comment: The time it takes to search a queue is highly dependent on the performance of the content's equal method. Sorry, but it's impossible for you to estimate "less than" anything for such an operation.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I think I'll try using the two collections. I thik the overhead will be worth it because the number of elements could potentially be very large. :)

Comment: @jarnbjo I used the words "should be" to mean, you should have some idea what the cost of your equals method i.e. its not an RMI call, and you should try to make it fairly cheap by comparing the field most likely to be different first.  It is possible you have a poorly tunes equals method and no access to what the equals method does, but thats not the way things should be ideally.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is something out there but you could easily create a compound object that consists of a `Queue` and a `HashSet`. All modifying operations need to occur on both collections at the same time to keep them in sync. You can then use the set for lookup which should be very fast.